# multi process failure - finding last function being used

Tags: c, debugging, eclipse-cdt, child-process

I am working on a complex code that use multi-process techniques.
I have 1 simulation process and 3 child processes.

The code compile with no errors and the software usually run OK and give good result. In some case, usually in long simulation runs, one of the child process send sigchld and the program is terminated.

Is there a way to force the child process to print the name of the last function being called before the error?

Is there a way to force the child process to print the line number of the last line being used before the error?

I am working with eclipse 3.8.1 under Ubuntu and the code is regular C.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do what you are asking, but I would suggest adding debug statements using a macro such as:

```
#define DBG_ENABLED 1
#if DBG_ENABLED
#define DBG(...) \
    do { \
        printf("%s(%d) %s(): ", __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__); \
        printf(__VA_ARGS__); \
        printf("\n"); \
    } while (0)
#else
#define DBG(...)
#endif
```

Then for example:

```
void YourFunction(int x, int y) {
    DBG("x=%d y=%d", x, y);
    . . .
    DBG("ok");
}
```

This allows you to see what your program is doing, and it should help pinpoint the location of the problem. Then you can set `DBG_ENABLED` to 0 to remove the debug from your executable.

(Probably better to use `fprintf()` to print to a file rather than `printf()` if you are running long simulations.)